# How to run external command and exit out of rust program without killing the spawned command

Tags: rust

Right now I'm trying to create a program that runs vlc, and then exits out of the rust program.

Here's the current implementation I have:

```rust
use anyhow::{Context, Result};

fn play_vlc(music_path: &str, vlc_args: &[&str]) -> Result<()> {
    let vlc_process = process::Command::new("vlc")
        .current_dir(music_path)
        .args(vlc_args)
        .output() 
        .with_context(|| "Error trying to play music")?;

    std::process::exit(0);

    Ok(())
}
```

This works fine, but since vlc is a continuous process, it never reaches `std::process::exit(0)` and so the program keeps running.

I have tried `.spawn()` rather than `.output()`, which allows the user to manually close the rust process and still have the vlc process running. But I want the rust process automatically closed, and now there's a bunch of output from vlc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are really good. Read them. All of what you're saying is expected behavior: [`.output()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.output) waits for the child process to finish. [`.spawn()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.spawn) lets the command inherit stdin, stdout and stderr when left to default. Which means, stdout on vlc will be the same thing as stdout of your Rust process. If your process can `println!` something, so can vlc, and it will go to the same place.

Now how to get around that? Essentially, you'll want to do the same thing that `>/dev/null` does in your shell. [`.stdout(…)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.stdout) allows to configure what happens to stdout, you want to redirect it to nowhere:

```rust
.stdout(process::Stdio::null())
.stderr(process::Stdio::null())
.spawn()
```

I was a bit surprised to see that this is offered by std, I expected this to require some platform dependent operations. Lucky you.